MariaDB connector для .NET Core
Подскажите рабочий MariaDB коннектор для проектов на базе .NET Core 2.2. Пробовал официальный MySQL - ругается на зависимости "System.Security.Premission" и "System.Drawing.Common", Devart.MySql ругается на ключ лицензии. Предполагаю что они не совместимы с .Net Core т.к. в WinForms приложениях работают.
